# In PhaserJS, how do I get a clicked Physics.P2 body's data?

Tags: 2d, physics, phaser, selection

I have a sprite with `Phaser.Physics.P2` enabled, using a custom shape loaded with `loadPolygon()` from a `.json` file. I have also activated its **debug** and **debugBody** properties, so I can see the custom shape:

[image: as shown here]

How could I collect the shape data information when I click on the debug shape?

For example, if I were to click the head of the sprite, can I get the polygon information from the click event?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at how phaser debug works: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.4.2/src/physics/p2/BodyDebug.js

On line 90 you have the 'draw' function that shows you how phaser draw the shapes.

If you take a look at the last part of the function you can have a way to get the verts of the polygons of each shape:

```
verts = [];
vrot = p2.vec2.create();

for (j = _j = 0, _ref1 = child.vertices.length; 0 <= _ref1 ? _j < _ref1 : _j > _ref1; j = 0 <= _ref1 ? ++_j : --_j)
{
    v = child.vertices[j];
    p2.vec2.rotate(vrot, v, angle);
    verts.push([(vrot[0] + offset[0]) * this.ppu, -(vrot[1] + offset[1]) * this.ppu]);
}

this.drawConvex(sprite, verts, child.triangles, lineColor, color, lw, this.settings.debugPolygons, [offset[0] * this.ppu, -offset[1] * this.ppu]);
```

So what you can do is, on click event, get the X and Y of the click and then, create a polygon for each shape (modifying the code from above) and for each polygon, check if it [contains](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Polygon.html#contains) the position of the click.